# Hard Drive Clone Proofing or Licensing to One Computer only

Tags: hard-drive, clone, license

Is there any way possible to prevent others from cloning my hard drive? or set one hard drive to work only with one computer? i tried to research but i did not see any topic related to it.

I have one original hard drive to be cloned, what i want to know is if it is possible that the cloned hard drives will never be cloned again and work only to one particular computer.

I hope someone could help with this one, thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, except of encrypting entire disk, so nobody except you with the password would be able to use the hard drive.

Comment: you think so, this is a hard topic eh.,

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten answer so it will reflect the two-part question better.

In short: yes, it's possible. You can do it in two ways: simple way or safe way.

Simple way is to put password on a hard drive in BIOS. This way disk is unusable unless password have been provided. Without password drive is unresponsive to commands. It is detected, but that's about it. Downside is - with certain vendors - if you forget password, disk is bricked. So forget any meaningful data recovery. I say ***some vendors*** because some drives store password unencrypted in firmware, so someone equipped with proper tools can access it. However, most modern SSD are resilient to that sort of attack and you may end up with a bricked drive if you forget password. So think hard on that one.

Another way is to encrypt drive. This, again, presents you with two basic options: hardware encryption and software encryption.
If you do not let your computer out of your hands, then software style is enough. It's because normally encryption keys are stored in RAM, so if someone gets his hands on your computer which is **not** powered down, they can extract keys from memory and have access to computer later, without your knowledge.

So Definitely go for OPAL standard (as described in second link) if you want to be secure - which would be, incidentally second option - hardware encryption.

I'm not sure how to classify TPM under my choice classification (it could be OPAL-compatible, but it's only one, most secure option out of several available). This one offers, I think, best safety-to-any-issues ratio. It combines hardware platform (TPM) and encryption (BitLocker for example) so that you can link drive to specific computer - for example if someone will take your drive out of computer and will try to clone it on his machine, disk will be inaccessible, as check is performed if it is connected to known, TPM-equipped system. If not, Bitlocker clams up.
Unfortunately, a lot of it rides on hardware in order to be achieved. First of all, you have to have a TPM compatible system, and at least v1.2 at that.
Then BitLocker ancryption needs to be activated.

One definite thing to check is how this affects non-boot drives (that is: how about **second** drive?). I am unsure how this works in that case.

Second thing to check is backup. Usually data needs to be decrypted in order to be backed up, so you need to be sure you have safe storage location for backups. And I definitely recommend backing up regularly when on SSD (no matter if encrypted or not - "hardware" failure rate on SSD is still way to high.
Also, some backup software do not support encryption (I'm simplifying here.). So check if you can do backup at all.

I am unfamiliar with cloning-counter technologies, so cannot help you with limiting number of times drive can be cloned. You can definitely do it with right software, but I don't think there's anything on the market, and even if, the requirement for it to work at all would be to put encryption on the drive in the first place.

More details:
http://web.mit.edu/cron/documentation/dell-server-admin/en/SUU/tpm.htm

http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper06.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two (sort of related) parts so I'll answer them individually:

1. Unless your disk controllers have some kind of security mechanism to prevent the controller being used in a different machine than the one it was originally tied to you will never get around someone "cloning" the disk. At present a disk controller is used before the disk contents are accessed (disk information, instruction sets etc.). Even if someone did obtain physical access to the disk they could swap the board for one that hasn't been tied to a machine (thus tying it to their own machine and being able to use the controller). Additionally, someone could even transplant the disk platters to another enclosure or clean environment and use recovery tools to copy the platter data.
2. As @AcePL's answer states, you can "tie" data to a particular device by means of encrypting the disk and use a TPM so that only that TPM can decrypt the disk. By using a TPM you can be assured that (if the TPM is truly unique!) if someone did clone your disk then they will never be able to decrypt it - much like public key encryption, you can have hundreds of copies of the disk but only one TPM will decrypt it - making it completely useless to anyone who has a copy of your disk but not the TPM.

Disk encryption can also work using a password (and other means such as a certificate on, say, a USB) which gives you other options so that you can put the disk into another machine and you enter your password to decrypt. This particular method - keeping to your question - wouldn't be very useful because the disk isn't tied to a particular hardware